# How to import the employee's work hours to TimeScaleData in microsoft project file using vsto add-in

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

How to import the employee's work hours to TimeScaleData in microsoft project file using vsto add-in?

Here is the sample data I have,

```
[{Name:"Phase 1", BaselineStart:"2023-01-01", BaselineFinish:"2023-03-30",
                Employees:[
                {Name:"John",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-12-01",Hours:6},{DateEntered:"2023-12-02",Hours:8},{DateEntered:"2023-12-05",Hours:9}]},
                {Name:"Rosy",EntryDates:[{DateEntered:"2023-11-04",Hours:2},{DateEntered:"2023-12-02",Hours:8},{DateEntered:"2023-10-16",Hours:9}]}
                ]
            }]
```

Here is my code, but it giving me an error like `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The argument value is not valid.'` at this line  `Assignment newAssignment = newPhaseTask.Assignments.Add(resource);`

```
Project project = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveProject;
Task newPhaseTask = project.Tasks.Add(phase.Name);
foreach (Employee emp in Employees)
{ 
 Resource resource = null;
 foreach (Resource projResource in project.Resources)
 {
     if (projResource.Name.Equals(emp.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     {
         resource = projResource;
         break;
     }
 }
 if (resource == null)
 {
     resource = project.Resources.Add(emp.Name);
 }
foreach (var date in emp.EntryDates)
{
 foreach (Assignment assignment in newPhaseTask.Assignments)
 {
     if (assignment.Resource == resource)
     {
         assignmentExists = true;
         break; // Exit the loop if an assignment for the resource is found
     }
 }
 if (!assignmentExists)
 {
     // Create a new assignment for the resource on the task
     Assignment newAssignment = newPhaseTask.Assignments.Add(resource);

     // Assign work hours to the specified date using TimeScaleData
     newAssignment.TimeScaleData(date.DateEntered, date.DateEntered, PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledWork, PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleDays, 1).Add(date.DateEntered, date.Hours);
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is my code, but it giving me an error like
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The argument value is
> not valid.' at this line  Assignment newAssignment =
> newPhaseTask.Assignments.Add(ResourceID: resource);

The argument value is not valid because the [Assignments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignments.add) method takes the resource's ID as an argument, not the resource object.

Try:

```
Assignment newAssignment = newPhaseTask.Assignments.Add(resource.ID);
DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now.Date; 
newAssignment.Start = targetDate;
newAssignment.Finish = targetDate;
newAssignment.Work = "8h";
```

Comment: I tried `Assignment newAssignment = newPhaseTask.Assignments.Add(resource.ID);` but still giving me the same error  `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The argument value is not valid.'`

Comment: Ah, sorry, the Resource ID is the second argument. So try: `Assignment newAssignment = newPhaseTask.Assignments.Add(ResourceID: resource.ID);`.

Comment: It seems `Assignment newAssignment = newPhaseTask.Assignments.Add(ResourceID: resource.ID);` is passed. but showing me the same error at `newAssignment.TimeScaleData(date.DateEntered, date.DateEntered, PjAssignmentTimescaledData.pjAssignmentTimescaledWork, PjTimescaleUnit.pjTimescaleDays, 1).Add(date.DateEntered, 6);`

Comment: TimeScaleData is a method, not an object, so it does not have an Add method (or any method). Search SO for posts about [how to use TimeScaleData](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-project%5Dtimescaledata).

Comment: Thank you, I used the `Assignment` object to add work hours. Here is the solution 
`Assignment newAssignment = newPhaseTask.Assignments.Add(ResourceID: resource.ID);
DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now.Date; 

newAssignment.Start = targetDate;
newAssignment.Finish = targetDate;
newAssignment.Work = "8h";`

Comment: can you suggest the correct solution. Because, Inside the loop, existing assignment is updating with new start, finish, work instead of including new. 
`Assignment newAssignment = testTask.Assignments.Add(ResourceID: resource.ID);
Resource resource = project.Resources.Add("Sridhar Netha");

foreach (EntryDate entryDate in entryDates)
{
    Assignment newAssignment = testTask.Assignments.Add(ResourceID: resource.ID);
    newAssignment.Start = entryDate.DateEntered;
    newAssignment.Finish = entryDate.DateEntered;
    newAssignment.Work = entryDate.Hours + "h";
}
`

Comment: See answer posted to your new question. Bottom line: in the code above, the Start and Finish dates for the assignment get reset for every entryDate. Better to use the TimeScaleData method to build an array of all dates for that assignment.